# How big would a balloon have to be for the shockwave to kill you?

Tags: science-based, death, explosions

I'm writing a tragedy in which my main character runs away using a giant balloon. Just as he realizes his folly, and decides it's time to return from whence he came, the balloon pops.

I want him to die.

Could the shockwave from a balloon popping kill little Timmy?

Comment: How does Timmy control the balloon's direction, elevation, etc? if he doesn't I'm guessing you could kill him more easily with the fall

Comment: As opposed to the fall killing him? The gas in aerostatic balloons is at or near at atmospheric pressure; the balloon won't "pop", except if it climbs too high where the envelope cannot expand to contain the gas; if the balloon is torn the gas will escape and Timmy will fall tumbling down.

Comment: Lighter than air substances pop "up" more than sideways when they burst their bounds. Unless he is on top of the balloon he wouldn't get the full force of the blast. Generally though, balloon deaths are from falling or fire, not the force of a shock wave. You would need more than 5G's of force to even approach lethality (about 49 m/s^2 acceleration) and the force would dissipate very quickly unless it was in a confined place like a tunnel or cavern that was mostly filled with the balloon. Also usually shockwaves hurt people when they impact something not when they move you in the first place.

Comment: Can you have the propane tanks of the hot air balloon explode instead?

Comment: Not size, but pressure.  Your question has no meaningful answer.

Comment: So, I’m changing the tags so @ThorstenS.’s answer is suitable.

Comment: Easy, it needs to be big enough to cause him to flinch. That can lead to a fall that kills him.

Comment: @JDługosz That works for me, thanks for making it a better question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Forget it, your deadly shockwave by simple popping is not going to happen**.

Balloons must be lighter than air which means either hot
air or helium/hydrogen. Hot air does not use closed balloons,
else you could not heat the air (While it is possible to
build a closed system, it is senseless. It only adds weight
and complicates the system).

Neither helium nor hydrogen are used under pressure at sea level (!)
because it only worsens the buoyancy and both gases are extremely
volatile and diffuse through nearly every material. Higher
pressures only worsens the diffusion. When hydrogen/helium balloons
are rising, the gas is expanding because of the lower pressure
until the balloon pops at a specific height.

As consolation I will tell how you can kill little Timmy.
You have the following options:

- **Asphyxiation**. If the balloon goes up, from 4000-6000 m
  little Timmy will get unconscious because the air is too thin.
  From 7000 m on (death zone) humans will sooner or later die,
  the sooner the higher the ballon is. Both helium and hydrogen
  are able to reach stratospheric heights (10 000 - 30 000 m).
- **Explosion**. Use contaminated hydrogen with air or oxygen
  which is the explosive oxyhydrogen. Let Timmy use an open flame
  or let the ballon rise through a cumulonimbus cloud (thunderstorm)
  and let lightning hit the balloon.
- **Fall**. Let him fall down because he is too stupid, he wants
  to commit suicide, the ballon loses air or is in flames (Hydrogen
  fire which is not explosive has almost no feelable thermal radiation, it
  won't burn you if you are not very near the flames. Helium does not
  burn). You can also let burst the balloon like weather balloons, the trouble is that it happen in a height where Timmy is already dead (first
  point).
- **Freeze to death**. Use a cumulonimbus cloud and let Timmy ride up and down with the down- and updrafts in heights where he can still breathe (something like 6000 m should suffice). In this heights the temperature has cozy -40 °C/F (yes, it is the temperature which is in both scales identical).

Your choice.

Comment: that was fun to read

Comment: +3 if I could, +1 because I can. Wasn't expecting the not possible, but excellent alternatives, thanks!